# Disable "a" href tag using code behind(c#) in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

For certain condition I want to disable my  tag and I have tried following so far

```
//codebehind
if(condition)
{
    aTag.Disabled.Equals(true);
}

//.aspx page
<a id="aTag" runat="server"></a>
```

it's not working, I don't know whats the matter, If anybody know please give me the better solution, thanks.

Comment: Just pull the `href` attribute or add `onclick="return false;"`. The `disabled` attribute doesn't do anything for links.

Comment: I think `Equals(true)` will only get the value and won't set it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `javascript:void(0);` to kill the link.

```
<a id="aTag" runat="server">You cannot click me!</a>

if(condition)
{
    aTag.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
}
```

Comment: scartag, your answer is also working but the problem is that it is still having the pageload..I found it correct in Win's answer, but @Win please update your answer as the code required in "if condition", so that people will not confuse while looking at the same problem....cheers all for their efforts !!

Comment: @Win There is also another problem that I noted, not sure. Actually,`Equals(true)` won't set the value, instead it will return whether its true or false (a bool value).

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the disabled html attribute .. not sure it works for links though.

```
aTag.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
```

**Update:** disabled doesn't work for links

Maybe what you need is to remove the value in the href.

```
aTag.Attributes["href"]= "#";
```

Or remove it.

```
aTag.Attributes.Remove("href");
```

Comment: This will produce `disabled="disabled"` in the HTML, which is the correct. `disabled="false"` is not if anybody is wondering.

Comment: @rhuges the `disabled` _attribute_ means _disabled_ regardless of which (or any) value is specified ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/ah725/)). Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything for links.

Comment: Why not set the visible property to false?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the href to javascript:void(0)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an `<asp:HyperLink Id="aTag" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="true" runat="server" />`

Set client mode to static if you need to reference aTag in javascript, otherwise you can remove that...

Then check it on server side:  `if condition { aTag.Enabled == false }` ...